# grepで正規表現を使用してパターンにマッチするファイル一覧を出力したい

Tags: linux, 正規表現, grep

grepでディレクトリ内のマッチするファイルの一覧取り出したいけど正規表現が上手く効かないです

```
grep -rnE '<SoundBox [\s\S]*?label=\\""' frontend

# マッチさせたい文字列
<SoundBox name={'Hoge'} checked={Hoge} label=""  />
<SoundBox label="" name={'Hoge'} checked={Hoge} onChange={Hoge} />
<SoundBox
  label=""
  name={'Hoge'}
  checked={Hoge}
  onChange={Hoge}
/>
```

詳しい方教えて頂けないでしょうか？
改行のパターンにもマッチしたいのですが、こちらだと上手くいかないです。

Comment: タイトルと内容が微妙にかみ合っていない気がします。「意図した通りマッチする正規表現を記述できない」なのか、「マッチした結果ではなくファイル名を表示させたい」のどちらがメインでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GNU grep` であれば `-P` オプション(`PCRE` engine)を使うと1, 2行目全てがマッチします。

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 3.7

$ grep -nE '<SoundBox [\s\S]*?label=""' frontend
2:<SoundBox label="" name={'Hoge'} checked={Hoge} onChange={Hoge} />

$ grep -nP '<SoundBox [\s\S]*?label=\"\"' frontend
1:<SoundBox name={'Hoge'} checked={Hoge} label=""  />
2:<SoundBox label="" name={'Hoge'} checked={Hoge} onChange={Hoge} />
```

ちなみに、`(\s|\S)*?` では両方にマッチします。

```
$ grep -nE '<SoundBox (\S|\s)*?label=""' frontend
1:<SoundBox name={'Hoge'} checked={Hoge} label=""  />
2:<SoundBox label="" name={'Hoge'} checked={Hoge} onChange={Hoge} />
```

Comment: これで改行も含まれるはずなんですけど、なぜかマッチしないです。`grep -nE '<SoundBox (\S|\s)*?label=""' frontend` なかなか上手くいかないものですね。

Comment: 自分が使用している。grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSDはバグが多いみたいですね。

Comment: `brew install grep` でGNU版をインストールしたんですけど `ggrep -rnP '<SoundBox[\s\S]*?label=""' frontend` マッチしないですね。

Comment: 複数行に対応するなら grep ではなく XML parser を使うべきでしょうね。もっとも GNU grep の場合は `-z` オプションを使ってマッチさせることもできますけれども。

Comment: 改行の箇所もいけますか？ `ggrep -rnP '<SoundBox[\s\S]*?label=""' frontend` 上手くいかないです。

Comment: 入れ違いになりましたが、改行の箇所は `grep -znP '<SoundBox[\s\n]*[\s\S\n]*?label=""' frontend | tr '\0' '\n'` などとするとマッチします。先程のコメントにも書きましたが、UNIX tools は基本的に「論理行単位」で処理するものなので、今回の様な処理には不向きになります。XML パーサをお勧めします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。この後ろにあるtrはなんでしょうか

Comment: 上記のコードを実行するとフォルダ内の全てのコードが出力されます。

Comment: 改行の箇所で 行の中に`<SoundBox` のみしか存在しないのにマッチするみたいな感じで書ければ `<SoundBoxTemp` とかを除外できるのですが、そのような書き方はあったりしないでしょうか？長々とすいません。

Comment: `-z` オプションの場合は色々と制約がある事を失念していました。 `grep -znPo '<SoundBox[\s\n]*[\s\S\n]*?label=""(.|\n)*?/>' frontend | tr '\0' '\n'` として下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 上手く全部抽出できたと思います。

Comment: `-z` オプションで改行を一度 `\0`で一行にして、その後に最初にマッチした箇所を出力その一覧をパイプで `tr` に渡して 改行に再び戻して出力しているのですね。

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -rnE '<SoundBox\s.*?label=""'
```

でいかがでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。上手くいきました。`[\S]` はgrepでは使えないのでしょうか？

Comment: `name={'Hoge'} checked={Hoge} label=""`には空白が入っているので、空白でないにはマッチしません。なので、空白を含むことが出来る`.*?`にしました。

Comment: [\S]の大文字が \s の否定系を表していて空白以外という事で全ての文字列に一致するようになるという使い方をよく見かけるのでおそらくgrepではこの \Sで空白以外という使い方が出来ないのですね。

Comment: いえ、`name={"Hoge"}`と`checked={Hoge}`の間に空白がありますよね？つまり、検索対象は空白文字を含むから`\S`ではマッチしないのです

Comment: この `[]` で囲われている中の物はどちらもパターンに適応されるはずでは、Python等の正規表現ではマッチします。

Comment: Pythonだと `<SoundBox [\s\S]*?label=""` これで両方マッチします。

Comment: ご利用の環境が解りませんが、macOSの`grep`は`[\s\S]`で確かにマッチしますね。ただし、`[\s\S]`は`.`と等価なので、`.`と書きました

Comment: 自分もmacでプロンプトにfishを使ってます。

Comment: 逆にzshだと上記のコードでうまくいきません。よく分からないですね。

Comment: なんか知らないけどそういうものだと、今回は諦めましょう